# How to read and write a Cassandra table using Spark Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

So, I figured out that when we have to create a dataframe using Cassandra keyspace and table name, the below given piece of code will do the job.

```scala
val df = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
  .options(Map("table" -> "table_name", "keyspace" -> "keyspace_name"))\
  .load()
```

Now, after modifying the above df(dataframe), I want to put it back to the same table by overwriting the initial contents.

I tried putting write instead of read, but it doesn't work.

How to overwrite the content of Cassandra table with the modified dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write` works just fine (example is from [documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md)):

```
df.write
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map("table" -> "words_copy", "keyspace" -> "test"))
  .mode(org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Append)
  .save()
```

But you need to be careful with writing back, if you modified the content of partition & clustering columns, you won't overwrite the data, but insert new data...

Comment: I'm getting error that savemode set to ErrorIfExists. If I'm using `.mode(SaveMode.Append)` then the error will be 
**error: not found: value SaveMode**
        **.mode(SaveMode.Append)**

Comment: You either need to add `import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode._` to get access to `Append`, or use fully qualified name - I've updated example correspondingly...

Comment: **org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:** This is the new error :(
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twitter/jsr166e/LongAdder**

Comment: It could be that you're running the jar with only of your code, instead of running the "fat jar" that will include all necessary dependencies (except `spark-core`)... Look to this article, for example: https://nosqlnocry.wordpress.com/2015/02/27/how-to-build-a-spark-fat-jar-in-scala-and-submit-a-job/

Comment: I'm simply using Apache Zeppelin

Comment: Hmmm, it should work without much problems, if you correctly specified dependency to cassandra-spark-connector in the Spark Interpreter... I did use it multiple times